# Problem while fitting this linear regression in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, linear-regression

I was trying to work with two arrays just to practice where I wanted to plot them - first to see them, then create a model which is linearRegression, and then fit the data and predict it.

Finally, I wanted to draw the linear regression line that separates them, but I am not able to - it doesn't draw it. This is my code:

```py
k_true = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]
k_pred = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,21]
plt.scatter(k_true,k_pred)
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit([k_true],[k_pred])
predictor = model.predict([k_pred])
plt.scatter(k_true,k_pred)
plt.plot([k_true],predictor,color="red")
```

[This is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kKq0O.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were plotting the wrong independent variable and also `predictor` needs to be replaced by `predictor[0]` since it contained a list within a list. You need to use `k_true` as x.

```
plt.scatter(k_true, k_pred)
plt.plot(k_pred, predictor[0], '-k');
```

[image]